# Unity2D Platformer: Player needs a key before using Door

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to C# and been trying to make a 2D platformer game by learning specifically what I need. I am kinda stuck atm.

I have tagged the Door with "Next" and programmed the player to enter "level 2" scene when it collides with anything tagged with "Next".

I want the player to obtain a Key before this script can take effect, and i have no idea how to code it.

I know this isn't the most optimal code, but this is what I used to make the game load next level

```c#
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Next"))
     { SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 2");}
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a boolean called `bool key = false;` and then set it to true the moment you pick up the key.

**Key PickUp (lies on Player GameObject)**

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Key")){
        // Key has been collected
        key = true;
        // Destroy Key after we've collected it
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

When you've done that you can just ask if the player has a key when he enters the door, if he doesn't have a key he can't enter.

**Door Enter Example (lies on Player GameObject)**

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    // Checking if Player Entered the Door Trigger and if he collected a key
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Next") && key) {
        // Key was "used"
        key = false;
        // Load Scene next in the BuildIndex Order
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

To use the the Code shown above you would need to make the Key a GameObject with a Collider that has `IsTrigger` set to `Active`. As well as adding both Code parts into your Player Script where you are already detecting the `Collision` right now.